# Do you have to check whether 'REQUEST_METHOD' exists in the $_SERVER variable before using it?

Tags: php

Do I have to check whether the `$_SERVER` variable has a key `REQUEST_METHOD` before actually using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`?

That is, is it overly defensive to *always* check whether a key exists in array variable like `$_SERVER`?

Comment: Why not just use `isset` ??

Comment: That's kind of...not the point of the question.

Comment: wow!, first time that I think it. makes me nervous :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP-manual [says the following](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) about the $_SERVER-variable:

> There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these;
>   servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a
>   large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1
>   specification, so you should be able to expect those.

The [CGI/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) has the following to say:

> The REQUEST_METHOD meta-variable MUST be set to the method which
>   should be used by the script to process the request, as described in
>   section 4.3.

and

> The Request Method, as supplied in the REQUEST_METHOD meta-variable,
>   identifies the processing method to be applied by the script in
>   producing a response.  The script author can choose to implement the
>   methods most appropriate for the particular application.  If the
>   script receives a request with a method it does not support it SHOULD 
>   reject it with an error (see section 6.3.3).

It probably isn't necessary to check for its existense if you aren't doing any CLI-development and the script will only be run from a server like Apache. You could probably do it, to be on the safe side, but it is of no necessity.

Comment: Wow, I totally skipped over that description. Ha! Thanks. That's exactly what I was wondering.

Comment: +1, for referencing the relevant specs related to REQUEST_METHOD particularly.

Answer (score 5):

Since you can't really ever guarantee what keys any PHP array will have you should always check them. That is not overly defensive and is good practice on your part.

For the sake of other readers with similar questions, you'd generally choose among these three methods for checking the array:

```
array_key_exists("REQUEST_METHOD", $_SERVER)
```

or

```
isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
```

or else you should escape the warnings with @:

```
$someVar = @$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

The last option is definitely not recommended as it tends to hide problems so I'd stick with the practice of checking for the presence of keys on any array, even the global PHP arrays.

Comment: I wasn't actually wondering what to use to do the check. The point of the question is whether a check is necessary in the first place, which is why I asked about whether it's defensive to do that...always.

Comment: @DarrenGreen, Yes, I guess it wasn't obvious from my response, but I could tell you already knew how to check them. I was just listing all the possible options for completeness sake for other readers.

Comment: Added a few more comments for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is interested in the value in `REQUEST_METHOD` then it's probably run from a web browser not the CLI, so in that case I wouldn't bother doing an `isset()` check. `REQUEST_METHOD` will always be there unless running from the CLI, since by definition of HTTP, a browser can't request a page without a request method.